# Print: Can't find symbol

Tags: java

I'm having a small problem with my tic-tac-toe program, this is the code for the creation of a cell. I am using the ACM library, so no need for `System.out`.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Cell {  
    Cell_content content;  
    int row;
    int col;

    // Constructor to make an empty cell
    public Cell(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col; 
        content = Cell_content.EMPTY;
    }

    //Content to print inside the cell
    public void cellPrint() {
        switch (content) {
            case CROSS:  print(" X "); break;
            case NOUGHT: print(" O "); break;
            case EMPTY:  print("   "); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the complete error message and indicate which line causes it.

Comment: Why can't you just use `System.out.println`?

Comment: 1) All the print's
2) Our teacher asked us so

Comment: Why would your teacher do such a thing?  The two answers posted here both imply that a `Cell` is some kind of `Program`.  I would ask your teacher whether this makes any sense at all to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`print()`](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html#print%28String%29) is defined in the `abstract class Program`, just importing this doesn't do anything.

You have to extend the abstract class to make the `print()` method available to you.

```
public class Cell extends Program { }
```

Comment: This was the problem... Thanks a lot! Didn't know that :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend from one of ACM's `Program` classes to avail of the [print](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1114/api/acm/acm/program/Program.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
public class Cell extends ConsoleProgram {
```

Comment: This was the problem... Thanks a lot! Didn't know that :/